# Стилизация и вывод кода в определенной области php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, функции

уважаемые друзья.Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть код вида:

```
введите сюда код
```

/*
 * Демонстрация старого способа работы с базой данных MySQL
 */

```
# Соединение
mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '1234**') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

# Выбор базы данных
mysql_select_db('***') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');
 # Кодировка
 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

# Выполнение запроса
# Выполнение запроса
$query = "SELECT * from vegas_Images";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

# Фильтрация строк и вывод нужной информации
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row["title"];
        echo $row["description"];
        <div> echo '<img src="'.$row["file_path"].'">';</div>
    }
```

Как его оформить так, чтобы результат можно было выводить где угодно на странице и оформить блоками div например title выводит заголовок с базы и я хочу его выводить поцентру и оформить красиво используя css.
нужно ли мой код заганять в функцию и потом вызывать где необходимо на странице ?

Comment: mysql уже забыть пора ... либо PDO либо Mysqli, уже 2018 год и php 7.2 есть а вы ещё старые драйвера используете

Answer (score 0):

Очень плохо, когда ты генерируешь HTML в PHP, правильнее использовать изолирование от HTML, вот тебе [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) по этому поводу.

Вот так:

```
    <html>
       ...
       <body>
        <?php
        # Соединение
        mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '1234**') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

        # Выбор базы данных
        mysql_select_db('***') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');
         # Кодировка
         mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
        mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
        mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

        # Выполнение запроса
        # Выполнение запроса
        $query = "SELECT * from vegas_Images";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

        # Фильтрация строк и вывод нужной информации
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
                <div><?= $row['title'] ?></div>
                <div><?= $row['description'] ?><div>
                <div>'<img src="<?= $row['file_path'] ?>">';</div>

        <?php endwile; ?>
       </body>
       ...
</html>
```